# "Wrong entity ID" error when adding 2 new customer attributes

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

**Magento 2.2.8**

I am trying to add a text and multiselect attribute to the customer. Here is my code:

```
namespace Foobar\CustomerFields\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {
   private $customerSetupFactory;

   public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory) {
       $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
   }

   public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
       $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
       if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0) {
           $customerSetup->addAttribute('field1', 'field1', [
               'label' => 'Feld 1',
               'input' => 'text',
               'type' => 'text',
               'source' => '',
               'required' => false,
               'position' => 1,
               'visible' => true,
               'system' => false,
               'is_used_in_grid' => false,
               'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
               'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
               'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
               'frontend_input' => 'hidden',
               'backend' => '',
               'adminhtml_only' => 1,
           ]);
           
           $customerSetup->addAttribute('field2', 'field2', [
               'label' => 'Feld 2',
               'input' => 'multiselect',
               'type' => 'text',
               'source' => '',
               'required' => false,
               'position' => 1,
               'visible' => true,
               'system' => false,
               'is_used_in_grid' => false,
               'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
               'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
               'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
               'frontend_input' => 'hidden',
               'backend' => '',
               'adminhtml_only' => 1,
           ]);

              $attribute=$customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                ->getAttribute('field1','field1')                                  
                ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                   'adminhtml_customer'                   
                  ]
                ]);
           $attribute->save();
           
           $attribute=$customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                ->getAttribute('field2','field2')                                  
                ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                   'adminhtml_customer'                   
                  ]
                ]);
           $attribute->save();
       }
   }
}
```

As soon as I run the upgrade command after enabling the extension I am getting "Wrong entity ID" when my extension is being upgraded. I already tried adding only one attribute, same error. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see function:
*\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)* to understand what parameters to pass. 
In here, $***entityTypeId*** must be value of **entity_type_code** column in table **eav_entity_type**.
[image]

And, you are adding customer attributes. So, $***entityTypeId*** value in here is **customer**, you should use \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY instead of text 'customer'.